Can I connect batteries of same voltage but different aH for my sump pump back up batteries?
I found much cheaper AGM deep cycle marine batteries and want to connect these in parallel to my already existing Sumpro set up. (https://www.ionproducts.net/literature/battery-backup-systems/legacy-products/SUMPRO75_OM.pdf)
The way my Sumpro is currently set up, I have two 12V 120aH batteries and I want to parallel this to two more batteries of different brand which are 12V 100aH batteries.
Should be fine right?

The first analysis is to figure out how much the pump, in rainy conditions (like when power is likely to go out!) uses per day to keep the sump under control. Multiply by how many days you want the backup, and then an additional factor that depends on the batteries. Regular lead-acid or AGM batteries put out somewhat more than half of their rated amp-hours, modern lithium batteries get closer to 90% of their rating (both when new). A decent battery management system is needed to keep the output voltage near nominal. Considering aging as well, you might need up to 4x your calculated amp-hours.

Is it already AGM deep cycle? Seems not since book says group 27.  Mixing battery types will produce a bad experience.  So will buying el-cheapo crud mail order whose specs are not accurate.... which is the only way I can imagine you beating the price of a group 27 at a battery dealer, NAPA or CostCo.  These things are commodities to the extreme. They already did you a huge solid by picking the most commodity battery type in North America.

The brand difference isn't a problem. Paralleling battery banks, on the other hand, is often a problem. Combining new and old batteries of different capacity aggravates that somewhat.
You'd be better off with six 2V 350-500AH batteries in series (or three 4V or two 6v) as a single string in series is much less prone to problems.
Parallel banks have a tendency to get out of balance. Parallel banks wired without careful attention to reducing (won't ever eliminate it) that are worse - if cables go from the pump/charger to one battery and then on to the next, that's worse. Those cables should go to each end of the bank as a whole, and the + & - ends of the bank connection are from batteries 1 & 4 of a 4 battery bank to better balance charging and discharging.

And don’t try to parallel different battery types (eg AGM and lithium). That is a bad thing to do since they are different voltages (small but significant) and charging requirements.

One approach to making better use of two new 12V batteries that don't match what you have would be a 24V charger and a 24V pump, and set those up as an independent system in the same sump.


I found much cheaper AGM deep cycle marine batteries

New AGMs?  You don't understand their specs, or they are lying about them.
Group 27 batteries are absolutely the most commodity battery in North America. Evvvverybody sells them from Tractor Supply to every auto parts to CostCo.   You won't find an AGM that is cheaper, unless it's really dodgy.
That vendor made some very pro-consumer / pro-Right to Repair choices by swerving out of their way to choose Group 27/31 instead of something proprietary or costly that you can't buy at any sane price in single quantity. Like every boost charger and many UPS's lol.
But to answer your question, AGMs use a slightly different charge curve from flooded lead-acids.  A charger made for floodeds can destroy AGMs over time.
